# ok i made the gif move but now i can not scroll on my website

Tags: java, html, css

when i pasted the code at the bottom of the site, where i wanted the gif to move, but now i can not even scroll. please help this is a big issue. the entire code is too big so ill just [link my codepen :)](https://codepen.io/mr_dog/pen/xxqjJKW?editors=1000)

its saying i need code to link my pen so im just gonna indent a hello world because im not gonna paste all of the damn code lol

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Hello World<h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `marquee` element is a unholy survivor of the 90s. You should not use it. You should use CSS-animations/transitions for this.

Comment: the only way i learned to use css animation is for linear gradients, would that work the same way?

Comment: @Anton could you help me with this?

Comment: naturly man, just modify overflow: hidden by overflow-x: hidden ;)
overflow on body makes you unable to scroll left to right and up to down, 
overflow x will then just makes you unable to scroll from left to right :)

Comment: ok so i removed the overflow and i can scroll, and now my animation is not working. did i put it in the wrong place? did i screw something over when i pasted the code? why does html have to bee such a pain sometimes

Answer (score 1):

This one is the good one :

```js
var sushi = document.getElementById('sushi');

sushi.addEventListener('click', function(){
    sushi.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
        body{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #sushi{
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            visibility: visible;
        }
        #sushi.active{
            animation: leftToR 6s 1 linear;
        }

        @keyframes leftToR{
            0%{
                left: 0;
                visibility: visible;
            }
            25%{
                left: 50%;
                visibility: visible;
            }
            50%{
                left: 100%;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            75%{
                left: -30%;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            76%{
                visibility: visible;
                left: -30%;
            }
            100%{
                left: 0;
                visibility: visible;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div id="sushi">
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/4YzoaFKXaGHbpkOnV3/giphy.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: it was just a little buggy when i played it so i tinkered with it for a sec and at 76% it kind of glitches in while its offscreen, so i fixed it so that it stays offscreen without it bugging out. now all i have to do is shorten the time its offscreen, thanks!

Comment: you're welcome don't hesitate to recommend this answer for people that will reach this topic if they got stuck ;)

Comment: i figured out how to edit the code so that its flawless!!! i am so happy :D

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it with the help of @Anton, thank you!

here is the code i used:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sushi</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #sushi{
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            visibility: visible;
        }
        #sushi.active{
            animation: mymove 3s infinite linear;
        }

        @keyframes mymove{
            0%{
                left: 0;
                visibility: visible;
            }
            25%{
                left: 25%;
                visibility: visible;
            }
            50%{
                left: 50%;
                visibility: visible;
            }
            75%{
                left: 75%;
                visibility: visible;
            }
  
            92%{
                visibility: hidden;
                left: 100%
          }
            95%{
                left: -10%;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
          100%{
            left: 0%;
            visibility: visible;
          }
        }


    </style>
    <div id="sushi"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/4YzoaFKXaGHbpkOnV3/giphy.gif"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        sushi = document.getElementById('sushi');

        sushi.addEventListener('click', function(){
            sushi.classList.add('active');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

hell yess!!

Comment: very well played :) antoncovu.fr

Comment: thank you :) it took a lot of trial and error because the sushi just kept glitching everywhere and moving at different speeds

Comment: the only issue i have with it is that it starts too far, im changing that now